# SQL - buscar dados de tabelas diferentes sem relacionamento com IDs

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, inner-join

Tabela pessoa_juridica (id, cnae, cnpj, ...) (quantidade de registros 40M) 
Tabela cnae_secundario (id, cnae, cnpj) não tem amarração por id com a tabela pessoa_juridica a única amarração é pelo cnae. (quantidade de registros 50M)

O usuário irá informa o cnae e preciso buscar tanto as pessoas_juridica que possuem esse cnae,
quanto as pessoas juridicas que possuem esse cnae como secundario.

Cheguei nesse SQL porém a consulta ficou muito muito muito demorada.

```
Select * FROM 
(   
    SELECT pj.id, pj.cnpj
    FROM Pessoa_Juridica pj 
    WHERE 
    pj.cnae in ('6499999')
    
    UNION
    
    SELECT pj.id, pj.cnpj
    from cnae_secundario c
    join pessoa_juridica pj on pj.cnpj = c.cnpj
    where c.cnae in ('6499999')
    and pj.cnae not in ('6499999')
) as empresas
```

Comment: Ola @bob, acho que um UNION ALL deve resolver seu problema

Comment: Oi @ViniciusDutra eu cheguei a usar o UNION ALL tbem, mas o problema é que esta muito demorada a pesquisa, e tem vezes q chega dar problemas de memória, queria ver se tem alguma solução q nem utilize o UNION e tal.

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema (incluso índices, estruturas etc, quem sabe o explain das queries) e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Comment: Como diabos dá para fazer um exemplo com quantidade de registros 40/50M ?! Banco de Dados não é sempre fácil reproduzir o problema @Bacco , com a devida vênia como dizem no STF...daria para melhorar a pergunta ? Daria , nisto eu concordo.

Comment: @Motta um exemplo verificável não precisa (nem deve) ter os 50M. Qualquer exemplo básico com meia dúzia de linhasa já vai revelar falhas estruturais e problemas com índice, e já serve para um explain. Se alguém tiver necessidade de ir alem, gerar 50M localmente teoricamente deve ser um requisito básico pra qualquer pessoa que queira dar uma resposta melhor elaborada (mesmo assim, já seria um extra).

Comment: @Bacco muito tópico tem realmente baixa qualidade (ou nenhuma) mas aos moderadores peço que reflitam antes de fechar , nem sempre é decisão fácil.

Comment: @Motta este tipo de discussão é pro site [meta]. Sobre o caso específico, zero dificuldade, é uma situação clara de fechamento (a resposta só serve para o autor, o que atesta que o fechamento foi correto, afinal [não somos site de ajuda, nem helpdesk, e sim um reposítório de conhecimento para público amplo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/7)).  Não sou contra ajudar, claro, mas manter isso por longo prazo obviamente não é a função do site. Da forma como está, o problema do autor foi resolvido. Se fosse editada conforme orientado, a energia investida talvez servisse para mais gente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--tente

```
SELECT pj.id, pj.cnpj
    FROM Pessoa_Juridica pj 
    WHERE  ( pj.cnae in ('6499999')
             or
             exists (SELECT null
                     from cnae_secundario c
                     where c.cnpj = pj.cnpj
                     and c.cnae in ('6499999')) )
```

Comment: muito obrigado funcionou a tua solução, demorou um pouquinho mas foi, valew